# How to make webpack module (inner logic) self execute?

Tags: javascript, webpack

This is the following module output that webpack generates:
I can see that it saves in the `window.webpackJsonp` array, however, the logic business of the module doesn't seem to execute in the case when I include the below result on any other page from where the whole project sits (parallel subproject that doesn't have webpack architecture)

My question can somebody please give small insight of why it happens and if there a possible workaround to make this module:
- Make it independent and really self-executed it's business logic whenever it's loaded to the page
- or what webpack dependencies should be loaded previously on the page to ensure that it will pick up the modules registered in `webpack.webpackJsonp` and execute them

```js
(window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || []).push([
    ["xxx-fit-responsive/xxx-fit-responsive-package/src/main/jcr_root/apps/xxx/fit/responsive/par/alertribbon/clientlib/publish/alertribbon.publish.bundle.js"],
    {
        /***/ "../../../xxx-fit-responsive/xxx-fit-responsive-package/src/main/jcr_root/apps/xxx/fit/responsive/par/alertribbon/clientlib/publish/alertribbon.publish.entry.js": /***/ function (
            module,
            __webpack_exports__,
            __webpack_require__
        ) {
            "use strict";
            eval(
                'eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);\\n/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_es_array_index_of__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(\\"./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.array.index-of.js\\");\\n/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_es_array_index_of__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(core_js_modules_es_array_index_of__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__);\\n\\n\\nfunction _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError(\\"Cannot call a class as a function\\"); } }\\n\\nfunction _defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if (\\"value\\" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } }\\n\\nfunction _createClass(Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) _defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) _defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }\\n\\nvar AlertRibbon =\\n/*#__PURE__*/\\nfunction () {\\n  function AlertRibbon(el) {\\n    _classCallCheck(this, AlertRibbon);\\n\\n    if (!el) {\\n      return;\\n    }\\n\\n    debugger;\\n    this.$elements = {\\n      el: el\\n    };\\n    this.init();\\n  }\\n\\n  _createClass(AlertRibbon, [{\\n    key: \\"setElements\\",\\n    value: function setElements() {\\n      this.$elements.closeButton = this.$elements.el.querySelector(\'.alertribbon__closeButton\');\\n    }\\n    /**\\n     * @param {event} event\\n     */\\n\\n  }, {\\n    key: \\"slideComponentOutUp\\",\\n    value: function slideComponentOutUp(event) {\\n      var _this = this;\\n\\n      var eventType = event.type;\\n      var closeKeyCodes = [13, 32];\\n\\n      if (eventType === \'click\' || eventType === \'keydown\' && closeKeyCodes.indexOf(event.keyCode) >= 0) {\\n        this.$elements.el.style.maxHeight = \\"\\".concat(this.$elements.el.offsetHeight, \\"px\\");\\n        setTimeout(function () {\\n          _this.$elements.el.style.maxHeight = \'0px\';\\n        });\\n      }\\n    }\\n    /*\\n    This logic excludes element from keyboard navigation flow */\\n\\n  }, {\\n    key: \\"hideComponent\\",\\n    value: function hideComponent() {\\n      this.$elements.el.classList.add(\'alertribbon__base--hidden\');\\n    }\\n  }, {\\n    key: \\"addEventListeners\\",\\n    value: function addEventListeners() {\\n      this.$elements.closeButton.addEventListener(\'click\', this.slideComponentOutUp.bind(this));\\n      this.$elements.closeButton.addEventListener(\'keydown\', this.slideComponentOutUp.bind(this));\\n      this.$elements.el.addEventListener(\'transitionend\', this.hideComponent.bind(this));\\n    }\\n  }, {\\n    key: \\"init\\",\\n    value: function init() {\\n      this.setElements();\\n      this.addEventListeners();\\n    }\\n  }]);\\n\\n  return AlertRibbon;\\n}();\\n\\ndebugger;\\n\\nif (window.nc) {\\n  window.nc.loaderRegister({\\n    AlertRibbon: AlertRibbon\\n  });\\n  /*\\n  Location Finder workaround, since it doesn\'t use nc.loader for now (6.3 Release) */\\n} else {\\n  document.addEventListener(\'DOMContentLoaded\', function () {\\n    var $alertRibbon = document.querySelector(\'.alertribbon__base\');\\n\\n    if ($alertRibbon) {\\n      new AlertRibbon($alertRibbon).init();\\n    }\\n  });\\n}//# sourceURL=[module]\\n//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,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\\n//# sourceURL=webpack-internal:///../../../xxx-fit-responsive/xxx-fit-responsive-package/src/main/jcr_root/apps/xxx/fit/responsive/par/alertribbon/clientlib/publish/alertribbon.publish.entry.js\\n");\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:////Users/bohdan.afanasyev/Projects/xxx-internet-fit/xxx-fit-responsive/xxx-fit-responsive-package/src/main/jcr_root/apps/xxx/fit/responsive/par/alertribbon/clientlib/publish/alertribbon.publish.entry.js?'
            );

            /***/
        },
    },
    [
        [
            "../../../xxx-fit-responsive/xxx-fit-responsive-package/src/main/jcr_root/apps/xxx/fit/responsive/par/alertribbon/clientlib/publish/alertribbon.publish.entry.js",
            "xxx-fit-design/xxx-fit-design-package/src/main/jcr_root/etc/designs/fit/includes/es6-main-publish/clientlib/publish/loader/runtime.publish.bundle.js",
            "xxx-fit-design/xxx-fit-design-package/src/main/jcr_root/etc/designs/fit/includes/es6-main-publish/clientlib/publish/vendors/vendors.corejs/vendors.corejs.bundle.js",
            "xxx-fit-design/xxx-fit-design-package/src/main/jcr_root/etc/designs/fit/includes/es6-main-publish/clientlib/publish/vendors/vendors.default/vendors.default.bundle.js",
        ],
    ],
]);

console.log(`Modules loaded`, webpackJsonp)
```

Comment: Why do you think this code should execute something ? It simply pushes an element into an array, nothing more.

Comment: I understand that part, just curious to understand is it somehow possible to make module generated by webpack to become self execetutable or what outer dependencies needs to be injected in the same page that will go to this webpackJsonp array and executed code inside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using webpack for building an application it runs your's **entries** code when it will be **loaded**.

For example for the simple "Hello World" code, you will get something like this

```js
!function(arrayOfEntries) {
  var t = {};

  function runEntryByIndex(n) {
    if (t[n]) return t[n].exports;
    var o = t[n] = {i: n, l: !1, exports: {}};
    return arrayOfEntries[n].call(o.exports, o, o.exports, runEntryByIndex), o.l = !0, o.exports;
  }

  runEntryByIndex.m = arrayOfEntries, runEntryByIndex.c = t, runEntryByIndex.d = function(e, t, n) {
    runEntryByIndex.o(e, t) || Object.defineProperty(e, t, {
      enumerable: !0,
      get: n
    });
  }, runEntryByIndex.runEntryByIndex = function(e) {'undefined' != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, {value: 'Module'}), Object.defineProperty(e, '__esModule', {value: !0});}, runEntryByIndex.t = function(e, t) {
    if (1 & t && (e = runEntryByIndex(e)), 8 & t) return e;
    if (4 & t && 'object' == typeof e && e && e.__esModule) return e;
    var n = Object.create(null);
    if (runEntryByIndex.r(n), Object.defineProperty(n, 'default', {
      enumerable: !0,
      value: e
    }), 2 & t && 'string' != typeof e) for (var o in e) runEntryByIndex.d(n, o, function(t) {return e[t];}.bind(null, o));
    return n;
  }, runEntryByIndex.n = function(e) {
    var t = e && e.__esModule ? function() {return e.default;} : function() {return e;};
    return runEntryByIndex.d(t, 'a', t), t;
  }, runEntryByIndex.o = function(e, t) {return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, t);}, runEntryByIndex.p = '', runEntryByIndex(runEntryByIndex.s = 0);
}([function(e, t) {console.log('Hello World!');}]);
```

If you follow the statements above you will see that it will run the function which contains `console.log("Hello World")`.

If we are talking about dependency's code then it'll be executed when you require it. For example, we have two files "A.js" and "B.js". "A.js" depends on "B.js"

A.js

```js
console.log("A");
require("./B.js");
```

B.js

```
console.log("B");
```

If you build this application where A.js would be entry point than you will see output

```
"A"
"B"
```

Lets' change the order of statements inside "A.js"

A.js

```js
require("./B.js")
console.log("A");
```

In this case, the output will be

```
"B"
"A"
```

Webpack also allows you to build library code. You can read about it here https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/

If you are curious about what is "webpackJsonp" you can read about it here
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputjsonpfunction

Comment: Thank you for explaining the topic Maksim, I had a look later on the dependencies of the main project and found the file with the similar logic that you have posted in the answer :-)